# Validation event not recognised "does not contain a definition for cboApprover_Validation"

Tags: asp.net, validation, combobox, event-handling, devexpress

EDIT: This seems to be happening on all pages on my application with any newly created event.

I added a Validation event to a DevExpress ASPxComboBox. The ComboBox looks like:

```
<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cboApprover" runat="server" OnValidation="cboApprover_Validation">
    <ValidationSettings CausesValidation="True" EnableCustomValidation="True" ErrorDisplayMode="ImageWithTooltip"
            ErrorText="Please Select an Approver">
    </ValidationSettings>
</dx:ASPxComboBox>
```

In code I have the following:

```
protected void cboApprover_Validation(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ValidationEventArgs e)
{
     //Other code
}
```

When I run the page I get the following error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0117: 'ASP.holidays_holidayrequest_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'cboApprover_Validation'

I have other ComboBox's on the page with their own validation events which work without a problem. It is only this one that is proving problematic. What could be the problem?!

Comment: Please share the full source code (markup and code behind).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a D'oh moment.

I had changed the debug configuration to x86 somehow, its an x64 machine, and didn't work. Such a schoolboy error.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify if the event handling function OnSelectionChanged() is there in the code behind file. This error CS0117 is due to missing code behind function related to the comboxcontrol.

Comment: What has OnSelectionChanged() got to do with it?